# Need help to understand the difference between similar RegExp usage where 1 works and 1 doesn't

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm a big fan of stackoverflow, though I'm new to using regular expressions. I have a QND search utility that I wrote to help me find/report things I'm searching for in source code.  I'm having a problem with figuring out what's wrong with my pattern searching that's not returning a match string that includes all text between two double quotes.  In one search it works (looking for Session variables), but in a similar one (looking for redirects) it doesn't.

Here's a sample aspx.vb file that I'm testing against:

```
Partial Class _1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private strSecurityTest As String = ""
    Private strUserId As String = ""
    Private strPassword As String = ""
    Private strMyName As String = ""

    Private Sub sample()
        strSecurityTest = Session("UserID")

        If strSecurityTest = "NeedsLogin" Or
            strSecurityTest = "" Or
            Session("SecureCount") = 0 Or
            Session("CommandName") <> strMyName Then
            Server.Transfer("WebApLogin.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Sucessful match:**

```
When I look for all occurances of Session("*") with pattern ==> Session\(\"\w*\"\)
I get correct results.  Noting the above source code, I get 3 matches returned:

Session("UserID")
Session("SecureCount")
Session("CommandName")
```

**Failed matching:**

```
However when I try another search by replacing "Session" with "Transfer" ==> Transfer\(\"\w*\"\)
nothing is returned.  

I have also tried these matching patterns:
Server.Transfer("*") ==> Server\.Transfer\(\"\w*\"\)
*Server.Transfer("*") ==> \w*Server\.Transfer\(\"\w*\"\)

Each of these doesn't return any matches.

In my live code I tried removing vbCr, vbLf, vbCrLf before the regex match, but still no matches
were found.
```

**Symptom:**

```
A symptom that I see is when I remove the text from the right side of the pattern, up to and
including the \w* ... then the search finds matches ==> Transfer\(\"  However since the search 
is now open-ended ... I can't capture the value between the double quotes that I want.
```

**Sample VB code is:**

```
Private Sub TestRegExPattern(wData As String, wPattern As String, bMatchCase As Boolean)

    '
    ' Invoke the Match method.
    '                            
    Dim m As Match = Nothing
    If Not bMatchCase Then
        m = Regex.Match(wData, wPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Else
        m = Regex.Match(wData, wPattern)
    End If

    '
    ' If first match found process and look for more
    '
    If (m.Success) Then
        '
        '   Process match
        '

        ' Get next match.
        While m.Success
            m = m.NextMatch()
            If m.Success Then
                '
                '   Process additional matches
                '
            End If
        End While
    End If
    m = nothing
End Sub
```

I'm looking for some pointers to understand why my simple search only works with one particular pattern, and not another that only changes the leading text to be matched explicitly.

Comment: The `WebApLogin.aspx` contains a dot which is not a word char. You must replace `\w` with - at least - `[^"]*`. To support escaped quotes use `(?s)Server\.Transfer\(\"[^\\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\\"]*)*\"\)`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor!  Your answer showed that I didn't have the correct solution in mind ... which is to select any continuous set of characters between double quotes.  I can use this understanding to adjust my search utility to accomodate this use case.